# Python : Removing the contents of a cell based on a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a *.xlsx file as below -

```
           A                              B                        C
                                   [['Neutral']]                ['nan']
                                   [['Neutral']]                ['nan']
          Bad                      [['Negative']]               ['Bad']
          Meh                      [['Neutral']]                ['Meh']
                                   [['Neutral']]                ['nan']
```

I'm trying to remove all the `[['Neutral']] and ['nan']` values in column `B` and `C` ONLY if their value is `null`.

This is my code -

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(path)

for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    if pd.isnull(row[0]):
        # del row[1]
        # del row[2]
        row[1] = 0
        row[2] = 0
```

My code is finding all the null values perfectly but is not able to clear out the `B` and `C` column variable s.What am I doing wrong?

Expected output is-

```
       A                              B                        C


      Bad                      [['Negative']]               ['Bad']
      Meh                      [['Neutral']]                ['Meh']
```

And yes the blank spaces/cells should still exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
mask=df['A'].isnull()
df.loc[mask]=''
```

Output:

```
     A               B        C
0                              
1                              
2  Bad  [['Negative']]  ['Bad']
3  Meh   [['Neutral']]  ['Meh']
4
```

For this problem you don't need to use for loop in pandas,

Explanation

1. Find index of wherever A is blank
2. replace empty at selected index

EDIT:

To remove from specific columns,

```
df.loc[mask,['B','C']]=''
```

Comment: Is there any way i can be more specific? It works but it also deletes the rows in the other columns. Can i perhaps specify that if A is null then it should delete the row in column B not column C

Answer (score 1):

You can simply assign it by taking the indexes of null values

```
df.loc[df.A.isnull()] = ''
```

Out:

```
        A   B   C
0           
1           
2   Bad [['Negative']]  ['Bad']
3   Meh [['Neutral']]   ['Meh']
4
```